# Are all dependencies in a Java Maven project added to the classpath?

Tags: java, maven

Is it what happens when I build a project that all dependencies are added to the classpath?

Comment: Yes. The project is built with the dependencies on the classpath. It does not by default include the dependencies in the resulting jar file.

Comment: I mean ... mostly, yes. Some might only be added while compiling, others just for running and others yet just for tests, but "being added to the classpath" is the primary reason for dependencies to exist. Honestly I'm not quite sure what you're trying to understand here.

Comment: [This section](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#dependency-scope) describes which dependencies are put on the classpath in which scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

No is the short answer, but the answer is complicated, because it's often Yes, but not necessarily.

It depends completely on what you're doing. If you're compiling to a `war`, Quarkus, or SpringBoot jar, those plugins WILL include both `<compile>` and `<runtime>` dependencies on the class path. If you're doing anything else all bets are off, but the answer is "usually yes, but who knows".

All `<compile>` and `<provided>` dependencies are on the `javac` path during compilation phase. `<provided>` should be removed at runtime for the majority of "normal" builds, but again, if you're straying off the beaten path, all bets are off.